# Custom Headers And Footers Not Appearing

Tags: header-footer

I'm using the Custom Header/Footerlines module on a new document in Lyx, but the headers and footers aren't even appearing in the document.

I was using this module in my old document, and it works just fine. However, headers and footers aren't visible in the new one, even with all of the same settings in place(including page layout set to fancy).

The only differences between documents is that the new one has a custom title script placed in it(**everything before %Old Code**). Perhaps the graphicx or svgnames packages conflict with the Customer Header/Footerlines module, I'm not sure.

Any help you can lend to solving this issue is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Stylish Colored Title Page 
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (27/12/12)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Peter Wilson (herries.press@earthlink.net)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
% 
% Instructions for using this template:
% This title page compiles as is. If you wish to include this title page in 
% another document, you will need to copy everything before 
% \begin{document} into the preamble of your document. The title page is
% then included using \titleBC within your document.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}% Required to specify font color

\newcommand*{\plogo}{\fbox{$\mathcal{PL}$}} % Generic publisher logo

\usepackage{graphicx}% Required for box manipulation

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand*{\rotrt}[1]{\rotatebox{90}{#1}} % Command to rotate right 90 
degrees
\newcommand*{\rotlft}[1]{\rotatebox{-90}{#1}} % Command to rotate left 90 
degrees

\newcommand*{\titleBC}{\begingroup % Create the command for including the 
title page in the document
\centering % Center all text

\def\CP{\textit{\Huge Building Brands By Building Links}} % Title

 % Set the width of the curly brackets to the width of the title
{\color{LightGoldenrod}\resizebox*{\unitlength}{\baselineskip}
{\rotrt{$\}$}}} \\[\baselineskip] % Print top curly bracket
\textcolor{Sienna}{\CP} \\[\baselineskip] % Print title
{\color{RosyBrown}\Large AN ILLUSTRATED COLLECTION} \\ % Tagline or further 
description
{\color{LightGoldenrod}\resizebox*{\unitlength}{\baselineskip}
{\rotlft{$\}$}}} % Print bottom curly bracket

\vfill % Whitespace between the title and the author name

{\Large\textbf{Author}}\\ % Author name

\vfill % Whitespace between the author name and the publisher logo

\plogo\\[0.5\baselineskip] % Publisher logo
2012 % Year published

\endgroup}

%Old Code
\date{}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\CenterWallPaper{1}{PDF_Background_1.png}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please add a minimal working example (MWE): https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/124842.